# Junit , Mockito Integration with Vertx

Tags: vert.x

I am new vertx wanted to know which is the best junit framework and references that we should went through.

I tried using couple of things with mockito but services are not getting injected.
Please help in this.
**UPDATE:**

My TestClass looks something like this

```
public class GroupModeTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GroupMode.class);

    public static GroupModeService service;
    public static GroupModeDao dao;

    private GroupMode groupMode;

    private static GroupModeDao daoMock;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        logger.info("Starting Unit Tests for GroupMode");
        daoMock = mock(GroupModeDao.class);
        dao = new GroupModeDao();
        service = new GroupModeService(daoMock);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        logger.info("Mocking new GroupMode Entity");
        this.groupMode = new GroupMode();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFakeWithMockito() throws IOException {
        IGroupModeDao iGroupModeDao = mock(IGroupModeDao.class);
        GroupMode groupMode = new GroupMode();
        groupMode.setId(1L);
        groupMode.setModeType("unique");
        groupMode.setCreatedBy(1);
        groupMode.setCreatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
        groupMode.setUpdatedBy(1);
        groupMode.setUpdatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
        Single<Long> expected=Single.just(1L);
        when(iGroupModeDao.create(groupMode)).thenReturn(expected);
        GroupModeService groupModeService = new GroupModeService(iGroupModeDao);
        Single<Long> actual= groupModeService.rxCreate("unique",1);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is rather broad. Can you give an example of what you tried to do?

Comment: Please check the updated content.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are you using the Mockito extension for your test class (e.g. `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`)?... and 2) I might very well be missing something because I haven't looked at Vert.x in some time, but what part of this is Vertx-specific?

Comment: Hey my classes are not able to get injected to my test class basically. Can you help with injection of service class for unit testing in vertx.